# my div overflows in the initial render, after refreshing the browser it goes away, why? how to fix it?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

my app have 2 section inside of a div. one is a sidebar and other is the content column. the bug happens when i start the project (npm start), it overflows x direction. after I reload the page, the bug goes away. why is this happen? and how do i fix it? it always happen on the first render of the project.

```
<div className="xl:flex h-screen overflow-x-hidden bg-c-graywhite1">
 <div
      className={`h-full w-full xl:w-80 bg-c-dark px-4 py-6 text-white z-50 transition-transform ${
        navEnabled ? "translate-x-0" : "translate-x-[-100vw] xl:translate-x-0"
      } xl:flex flex-col justify-between fixed`}
    >
      ....sidebar
 </div>
 <div className="xl:w-full xl:ml-80">
  <Header />
  <div className="mx-3 xl:mx-12 mt-3 xl:mt-10">
   <Outlet />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```